# CryptographicEngine.DecryptAsync throwing " System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' " while CryptographicEngine.Decrypt doesn't

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying my hand on encryption and decryption on UWP platform and am stuck trying to figure out this one problem.
So first, I encrypt my string "Sample statement." using the following:

```
IBuffer bufEncrypted = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strToEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8), null);
string strEncrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(bufEncryptedStr);
```

Then, when I try to decrypt "strEncrypted" using:

```
IBuffer bufToDecrypt = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(strEncrypted);
IBuffer bufEncryptedStr = await CryptographicEngine.DecryptAsync(key, bufToDecrypt, null);
```

I get the error as "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'".

However, when I try the same decryption using:

```
IBuffer bufEncryptedSt1r = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, bufToDecrypt, null);
```

I don't get any error and can get the decrypted string using:

```
CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, bufEncryptedSt1r);
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Relevant info:

```
IBuffer bufKeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(256);
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
CryptographicKey key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(bufKeyMaterial);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I tested with your code snippet with `Decrypt` method of [`Cryptographic​Engine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine) class, it can work well and have the right result. So that you can just use `Decrypt` method.

```
IBuffer bufEncryptedStr = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, bufToDecrypt, null);
String strDecrypted = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, bufEncryptedStr);
```

For why the `DecryptAsync` method will throw the exception, this is expect behavior. According to the remarks of [`DecryptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine#Windows_Security_Cryptography_Core_CryptographicEngine_DecryptAsync_Windows_Security_Cryptography_Core_CryptographicKey_Windows_Storage_Streams_IBuffer_Windows_Storage_Streams_IBuffer_), you only need (and can) call `DecryptAsync` on persisted keys.

> If the key is a persisted key and the decrypt operation requires UI or takes a long time, use the DecryptAsync method instead of the Decrypt method

More details please reference [this similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f09bfff2-4656-442a-9160-3c42ebdb2217/cryptographicenginedecryptasync-invalidcastexception?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: I can't figure out why this wasn't mentioned in the Microsoft docs clearly enough. I didn't know that it would throw an invalid cast exception. Thanks!